# Regex [var1::var2]?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have tags in a string formatted like this 
    [var1::var2]. 
Var1 can be any length and any character, var2 is a link so http/https.
How do I do that and get the first var as $1 and the other as $2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have compared a few options in [**here**](http://jsperf.com/getting-vars). The best option seems to be using the `String.match` function with a **lazy** matching regex.

```
'[var1::var2]'.match(/^\[(.*?)::(.*?)\]$/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
> '[var1::var2]'.match(/\[(.*)::(.*)\]/)
["[var1::var2]", "var1", "var2"]
```

Comment: You should probably be using a lazy match instead of a greedy match.